# IntelliJ - Debug info window shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when a breakpoint suspends an a program.. If I hover over a variable with the mouse cursor and wait for a second or two, a tooltip appears, which lets me inspect the variable by clicking the `+` sign. For example in the below image, I kept my mouse cursor over `three` for a second or two and the tooltip saying `Main$Die@452` appeared.

[image]

Is there a way to show this tooltip only by using the keyboard and the current cursor location? In other words, in the screenshot above, how would I see the tooltip for the variable `one` (where my keyboard cursor is) without moving the mouse cursor over the variable `one`? (And how would I expand it once I see the tooltip?)

While debugging code, I realized I end up inspecting objects like this very often and moving around the mouse and waiting for the tooltip to appear starts to slow down the process a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action is called "Quick evaluate expression":
[image]

You can invoke it via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on macOS, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on Windows